# Best way to run remote commands on a Windows server from Java?

Tags: java, command-line, ssh

Are there any existing solutions for remote execution of commands on a windows server from Java natively? psexec.exe is not an option since the java application has to be cross platform.

Even a preexisting solution using Java RM would be sufficient.

Currently, I'm using an SSH client library to ssh through java into a Windows server that's running the cygwin SSH daemon. Sadly the SSH daemon has some issues when it comes to quoting commands that go into a CMD (as opposed to bash) shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Java RDP Client](http://www.elusiva.com/opensource/). Not really out of the box, but with little digging you should be able to trim it down to what you need.

Since it uses getopt, I would assume it's GPL'd.

Answer (score 4):

It'll require some work, but the remoting library in Hudson has very good support for running commands and doing file operations over the network on remote computers.

see https://jenkins.io/projects/remoting/ (you'll have to dive into the code)

Comment: Cool, thanks! Where exactly is the code located that is related to remote execution? Or is it all over the codebase?